# How to delete a OpenLdap Object in C#?

Tags: c#, openldap, directoryservices

I am using C# to manipulate openldap objects, now I can use System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry class to implement most of the methods (adding & modifying objects) expect for deleting an object. I am using the DirectoryEntry.DeleteTree method to delete an object now but I get an error:"treeDelete control value not absent". Does the method only work with AD? or I have to use DeleteRequest and LdapConnection classes in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols to delete an object?

I am wondering if there is a way and prefer to use DirectoryEntry to delete an object.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have come out the solution now, and it's quite simple, just like this:

```
            var de = GetAgentEntry();
            var pa = de.Parent;
            pa.Children.Remove(de);
            pa.CommitChanges();
```